How can I prevent any connection to the SQL Server database except through my application?
How can I prevent any connection or interaction with the SQL Server database except through my C# application? I have a system that I created using .NET and there are third-party applications that can access the database. I tried several solutions such as stopping Windows authentication or preventing login using trigger, but that did not work.
CREATE TRIGGER trg_restrict_app_access
ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
    IF ORIGINAL_LOGIN() = 'myUsername' AND APP_NAME() <> 'MyApp'
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        THROW 50000, 'Unauthorized application', 1;
    END
END;
GO


Why AND and not OR ?

Why are you worried about this?

This is an XY Problem. You want an X. You don't know how to get an X but thought that to "prevent any connection to the SQL Server database except through my application" would get an X. You tried that but didn't get an X. That's because, whatever X is, "prevent any connection to the SQL Server database except through my application" is not going to X. If you want us to help you have to explain what X is.

Your application should connect to the database using credentials (user-name/password).
You can configure the database to only allow access via those credentials.  This is usually done by creating a role that has the relevant permissions, and assigning that role to the user that your app. uses to connect with.
There are built-in roles that may serve your purpose, but if you want fine-grained control then you can create your own.
You can create roles and assign permissions via SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) or via a script.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16

I tried this solution but a third party app installed on the device is attach the mdf file on another instance.
